# Запуск приложения через определенную ссылку

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, форумчане.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть возможность запустить моё апп через определенную ссылку (из смс, из страницы не важно, просто по ссылке). Так вот запуская приложение я получаю эту ссылку и делаю с ней операции.
Но это всё работает только если апп уже не было запущено.
А когда запущено:
Да когда, я нажимаю по ссылке и выбираю моё апп, оно запускается. Но данные которые я пытаюсь получить (ссылка) в интенте уже нулевые.

Сначала я думал, что проблема в том что я запускаю сплеш скрин (а это первой активити при запуске приложение, которое ясно из названия убивается в последствии и больше не тревожит). Но когда я прописал интенты фильты в другую активити, которая не убивается, результат был такой же - при первом запуске работает, дальше нет, интент пустой.

С чем может быть связанна эта проблема?

Comment: для получения интента используете `getIntent` или Bundle, переданный в метод "onStart"?
да, и задайте нормальную тему.

Comment: getIntent() конечно а Bundle нет
Я задал, но почему генерик удалился

Comment: Может, `Activity.onNewIntent(Intent intent)` вам поможет?